# modeling datawarehouse multilanguage

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling, data-warehouse, powerbi-embedded

I need your help.

I work for a survey company and I am responsible for creating its architecture and modeling a data warehouse that analyzes the results of an international survey (50 countries).

For the architecture, we decided to create a tabular model in PowerBI to analyze our data and to create our reports.
Here below is the model as I thought:

[image]

However, I have a design problem.

Since the survey is international, the wording of my dimensions differs from country to country.

**My 1st question:**
-Would it make more sense to create only one PowerBI embedded model for all countries or 50 PowerBI reports?

**My 2nd question:**
My model must be multilingual
With my 50 countries, I have several languages (5 languages) and for the same language, I have several variants.

The British English labels differ from the US English labels.

For example, for the Response dimension for France the IdReponse = 1 has the wording 'Vrai' while for the USA the wording is 'True' and for the Britain is 'OK'.

Do you know how to model multi language in a data warehouse?

Answer (score 0):

About question #1 - It's always better, if there is only one model. It will be much easier to maintain. It isn't clear from your question will these 50 reports show the same data (excluding the internationalization of texts like Vrai/True/OK), or each report/country should show it's own subset of the data. In case all reports will show the same data, then definitely it will be better to make one common model and all report use it. You can do this with Power BI by making one "master" report and publishing it, and then the rest of your "per country" reports [use it as a data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-report-lifecycle-datasets). And you will need separate reports per country, because you will need to translate the texts (column names, static texts, etc.).

About question #2 - You can create lookup tables in your model (maybe even in the database, it's up to you). The key value (1) will be linked to the key of the table, and there will be columns per language. Depending on the language of the current report, you will select the appropriate column (e.g. French, British, etc.) and even you can fallback to let's say US English, in case there is no translation entered for the current language (e.g. by making a computed column). It is also an option to make separate lookup table per language, but I think it will be more cumbersome to maintain this way.

Answer (score 0):

About question #1:  Yes you need only one data model.

About question #2: You Load a question in the language it is asked and the response you get as is in the response DIM. You should create a new column in your response DIM such as Clean_response where you transformed original response to a uniformed value. for example "Vrai", "OK", "True" has same meaning so you may chose to put "Yes" in the Clean_response column. You can also convert different variation of "No", "Nada", "noops", "nah" to a clean value of "No", but keep the original value too.

Labeling a column in the report should be handle in the report code. For example writing a report in French should use your dim column name "Question" and show it as "interroger" as a heading on the report.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. So what do you think about this solution #4  of this link ?https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/data-modeling-for-multiple-languages-how-to-design-a-localization-ready-system ?

Comment: I provided the answer based on your question. If you need to translate data in English then you can use that approach.